# Change name in collection with multiple documents in MongoDB and Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

If I have a collection with multiple documents for one person like:

```
{ FullName: "Jane Doe", Camp: "may12", Week1: "0", Week2: "1", Week3: "0" }
{ FullName: "Jane Doe", Camp: "may13", Week1: "0", Week2: "0", Week3: "1" }
{ FullName: "Jane Doe", Camp: "may14", Week1: "0", Week2: "1", Week3: "0" }
```

and I need to update her name to "Jane Smith", I get her name from a Session:

```
var nameAddressFullName = Session.get('clientName');
```

Get all the documents with her name in put them into an array:

```
var documentNameAddressP = Programs.find({ FullName: nameAddressFullName}).fetch();
```

Then try to update all the names (I need to update based on _id values only), I'd need something like:

```
Programs.update({ _id: {$in: {documentNameAddressP._id}}, {$set: {FullName: nameChange}}); //????
```

We need to update all Jane Doe's documents to the full name Jane Smith keeping all the rest of the properties intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this update via a method call to server then you can bulk update all the documents there in one go with `{multi: true}` in your update query.

From the client you can easily iterate over the cursor:

```
Programs.find({ FullName: nameAddressFullName}).forEach(function(doc){
  Programs.update({ _id: doc._id },{ $set: { FullName: nameChange }});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Floyd! Does the 'multi' option need to be done on the server?

Comment: Yes, `multi` only applies to an update performed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can select element to update in update query:

```
Programs.update({FullName: nameAddressFullName},{$set: {FullName: nameChange}})
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: But I can only update a document's property value based on the _id.

Comment: In Meteor, it's for security purposes.

Comment: it's the same, to get id from name and then update with id, what is the difference with update by name ?